# Find the equation of the tangent-plane to the surface

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, surfaces

> Find the equation of the tangent-plane to the surface given with the equation
>   $$2x^2+5y^2+2z^2-2xy+6yz-4x-y-2z=0$$
>   that passes through the line $$4x-5y=0, \ \ z-1=0.$$

The equation of the slope-plane at the point $M(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by:
$$(2x_0-y_0-2)x+(-x_0+5y_0+3z_0-\frac{1}{2})y+(3y_0+2z_0-1)z-2x_0-\frac{1}{2}y_0-z_0=0. \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$
(just plugged the coefficients into the general formula of tangent-plane).

Also, as the plan passes through the line given, we obtain it is of the form
$$4x-5y+t(z-1)=0 \ \  \text{ or } \ \  4x-5y+tz-t=0 . \ \  \ \ (2)$$
but the system (with respect to $x_0,y_0,z_0,t$) obtained by equalizing the coefficients of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is inconsistent (has no solution). I got stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If a plane $\mathbf{n}_1.(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}_1)=\mathbf{0}$ passes through the line intersection of planes $\mathbf{n}_2.(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}_2)=\mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{n}_3.(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}_3)=\mathbf{0}$, then 1) $\mathbf{n}_1.\mathbf{n}_2=\mathbf{n}_1.\mathbf{n}_3=0$, 2) $\mathbf{n}_1.(\mathbf{a}_\ell-\mathbf{a}_1)=\mathbf{0}$ if you manage somehow to find a point $\mathbf{a}_\ell$ on the line( $(0,0,0)$ clearly fits by inspection). You have $3$ equations and $3$ variables ($x_0,y_0,z_0$). Can you solve it now?)

Comment: P.S. if $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ and $A_1x+B_1y+C_1z+D_1=0$ is the same plane it doesn't mean $A=A_1,\,B=B_1,\,C=C_1,\,D=D_1$, but only $\frac{A}{A_1}=\frac{B}{B_1}=\frac{C}{C_1}=\frac{D}{D_1}$ if none of them is $0$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin why should $n_1$ be perpendicular with $n_2$ and $n_3$?

Comment: OK you're right there's no reason. but the direction vector is parallel to vector product $[\mathbf{n_2}\times\mathbf{n_3}]$ and perpendicular to $\mathbf{n_1}$ -- it gives $1$ equation ($\mathbf{n_1}.[\mathbf{n_2}\times\mathbf{n_3}]=0$) instead of $2$. The third equation will be the surface equation itself for $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Sorry for misleading the first time.

Comment: To equate coefficients use a scaling factor $s$. In maxima CAS: `solve([(4*z0+6*y0-2)*s-4,(6*z0+10*y0-2*x0-1)*s+5,(-2*y0+4*x0-4)*s-t,(2*z0+y0+4*x0)*s+t],[x0,y0,z0,s,t]);`

But the solution $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(r,(92r-37)/46,-(276r-147)/92)$ is not on the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given line is tangent to the surface at point $P=(0,0,1)$. It suffices then to find the equation of the plane tangent to the surface at $P$, that is: $-4x+5y+2z=2$.